# Errors in php file with undefined indexes and I've tried everything

Tags: error-handling

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connection.php";
$date=date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
$_SESSION["end_time"]=date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($date."+ $_SESSION[test_time] minutes"));
include "header.php";
?>


    <div class="row" style="margin: 0px; padding:0px; margin-bottom: 50px;">

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3" style="min-height: 500px; background-color: white;">

            <?php
            $correct=0;
            $wrong=0;

            if(isset($_SESSION["answer"]))
            {
                for($i=1;$i<=sizeof($_SESSION["answer"]);$i++)
                {
                    $answer="";
                    $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from questions where catergory='$_SESSION[revision_topic]' && question_no=$i");
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                    {
                        $answer=$row["answer"];
                    }

                    if(isset($_SESSION["answer"][$i]))
                    {
                        if($answer==$_SESSION["answer"][$i])
                        {
                            $correct=$correct+1;
                        }
                        else{
                            $wrong=$wrong+1;
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        $wrong=$wrong+1;
                    }

                }

            }

            $count=0;
            $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from questions where catergory='$_SESSION[revision_topic]'");
            $count=mysqli_num_rows($res);
            $wrong=$count-$correct;
            echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
            echo "<center>";
            echo "Total Questions=".$count;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Correct Answer=".$correct;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Wrong Answer=".$wrong;

            echo "</center>";
            ?>


        </div>

    </div>

<?php




if(isset($_SESSION["test_start"]))
{

    $date=date("d-m-Y");
mysqli_query($link,"insert into test_results(id,username,test_type,total_question,correct_answer,wrong_answer,test_time)values(NULL,'$_SESSION[username]','$_SESSION[revision_topic]','$count','$correct','$wrong','$date')") or die(mysqli_error($link));

}

if(isset($_SESSION["test_start"]))
{

    unset($_SESSION["test_start"]);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href=window.location.href;
    </script>
    <?php

}

?>


<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

I have two errors

> "Notice: Undefined index: revision_topic in C:\xampp\htdocs\online-quiz\result.php on line 49"

and

> "Notice: Undefined index: test_time in C:\xampp\htdocs\online-quiz\result.php on line 5"

If anyone could help that would be great. It links into other files and I just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Notice the lack of 'quotations' around `revision_topic` and `test_time`. Change to `"revision_topic"` and `"test_time"`.

Comment: Hi it didn’t work adding the “” marks but when I deleted them the code started working so thanks!